# Deep linking in Compose Single Activity Architecture

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-deep-link

**Usecase**: Single activity Compose app handling Firebase Auth magic email link.

**Problem**: if app is already opened and the user clicks the link, a new task is created and there are two instances of the app in the Recents screen. I understand this is the default behaviour of the standard launchMode but I think it's confusing the average user and it doesn't make sense in login where the other task most likely contains just a Welcome screen.

**Proposed solution**: change launchMode of single activity to singleTask and call navController.handleDeepLink() in onNewIntent.

However, this solution goes against Google's recommendation to ["*always use the default launchMode of standard when using Navigation.*"](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#handle)

What is the best practice here?